# Akeneo import returning 500 on upload

Tags: akeneo

When creating a import-profile in Akeneo i.e. XLSX, and then trying to upload and import a file Akeneo shows the spinner for infinite time. When I use the inspector window i see that the POST request to /launch that is apparently part of the rest API ( baseURL /job-instance/rest/import/product_variant_import/launch ) is returning this 500 error preventing Akeneo from proceeding.

First i thought it might had something to do with upload permissions but uploading media works fine. Unfortunately because of the 500 error there is nothing in the apache logs.

I'm using the basic apache configuration that is suggested in the set-up guide ( https://docs.akeneo.com/3.1/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/manual_system_installation_debian9.html ) under Apache.

I can't find anything on this subject online (Akeneo import + 500 error), so hopefully any of you have suggestions on what might cause this.

Best,
Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the log and to have more information. And know what is happening exactly. If you can't check it, try to use xdebug to debug akeneo and stop it here:

**/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php**

Line 225:

```php
    private function handleException(\Exception $e, $request, $type)
```

And you will know what error you have.

**EDIT:**

We were talking via slack, and he sent me the error. He had problems due permissions

The error that he sent me:

```
“Impossible to create the root directory “/tmp/pim/file_storage/13_Product_variant_import_CSV”.
```